# Only 1 row is being inserted to table(SQLite/Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have been trying to create an SQLite database. But only one row is being added. (cursor.getCount() gives 1). Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

Dbhelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,"database00",null,1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TABLE00 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                       + "DISPLAY TEXT);");
    insertD(db,"a");
    insertD(db,"b");
    insertD(db,"c");

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion) {}

private static void insertD(SQLiteDatabase db,String display)
{
    ContentValues d=new ContentValues();
    d.put("DISPLAY",display);
    db.insert("TABLE00", null, d);
}}
```

Code that is accessing this info:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper Dbhelper = new Dbhelper(this); 
SQLiteDatabase db = Dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE00",null); 
cursor.moveToFirst(); 
int msg3 = cursor.getCount(); 
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3); textView.setText("No of rows:"+msg3); 
cursor.close(); 
db.close();
```

Comment: `cursor.getCount()` for what query?

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper Dbhelper = new Dbhelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = Dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE00",null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int msg3 = cursor.getCount();
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView.setText("No of rows:"+msg3);
            cursor.close();
            db.close();`

Comment: @Nandgopal Good response. Put it in the answer section to get the due credit for it.

Comment: textView displays "Now of rows:1"

Comment: @UsamaZafar: No, I'm the one who asked the question. I created the table as mentioned above and did this in another class. Only 1 row is created(No of rows is 1). I don't understand why.

Comment: @laalto: Could you find my mistake?

Comment: Nothing wrong there. But are you sure there are more rows in the table? May be there is one? Also try getCount() before moving the cursor to the first record.

Comment: @UsamaZafar i tried keeping getCount() before moving the cursor to the 1st record. it still gives 1. If i try to access the 2nd/3rd row i get `CursorIndexOutofBoundexception` .

Comment: Capture the new row id from here `db.insert("TABLE00", null, d);` and print it out to logcat.

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate()` is run only once when the database file didn't exist. Uninstall your app to remove the database file and make `onCreate()`  run again.

Comment: @laalto **I unistalled the app from the phone and ran it again** and now its proper. Thanks for the help and explation. Appreciate it.